# how can I have two while loops run at the same time? bash

Tags: bash, shell

Well i was just wondering how i can run like two while loops at the same time. I have heard of done& on a while loop and all but when i tried to use that it failed in the end. I have also heard using like a fork loop which i still don't understand.

if anyone has ideas can you give me a little example script so I can understand.
Also I am not rejecting done& and fork loops just don't know how to use them properly.

Comment: In parallel? Nested? What did you try (be detailed)? Why did `done &` fail in the end? Can you give an example?

Comment: while [ number == 1 ]; do sleep 1 echo "$time" done& while [ number == 1 ]; do sleep 1 time=$(echo "$time+1" | bc) done

Comment: this is only a small example of what i was doing in a way

Comment: in this it wont do the second part of the script adding to the time

Comment: Your example does not work, because each loop will be running in its own process (and modifying their own local versions of your variables).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ number == 1 ]; do sleep 1 echo "$time" done &

while [ number == 1 ]; do sleep 1 time=$(echo "$time+1" | bc) done
```

When you run the above script, the while loops are run as separate processes and they can't "see" the variable `time` as they'll have them as their own local variables. In order to send the data across processes, you have to use an IPC mechanism.

You can create a [**named pipe**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html) using `mkfifo` and send the `time` value from one process to another. The following a simple example of what you are trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo mypipe #Creates a named pipe

while read line<mypipe; 
do 
  sleep 1
  echo "$line" 
done & 

while : ; 
do 
  sleep 1 
  ((time=time+1))
  echo $time > mypipe
done
```

At the end of it, don't forget to delete the pipe. Simply do: `rm mypipe` (you can see it in your current directory with: `ls -l mypipe`).